# What does "?" mean in Erlang?

Tags: functional-programming, macros, erlang

I see alot of code in erlang with a question mark before it, what does it mean? Is it Macros or can it be used in another way? Example:

```
    {Total, Pids} = run(10, 20),
    ?assertEqual(200, Total),
    ?assert(processes_stopped(Pids)).

    or:

    ?MODULE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try call macros, you need add in start of name ‘?’. Notes: the macros can create with or without arguments.

Comment: So it's only used in the context of macros?

Comment: @slahslah90 yes, this is correct.